# Recursive descent parser that counts the number of 'a' and 'b' characters not counting correctly

Tags: c, recursive-descent

I'm writing a simple recursive descent parser that takes standard input and counts the number of 'a' and 'b' characters. The grammar for this is as follows:

S -> A B '\n'

A -> a A | empty

B -> b B | empty

```
int lookahead; 

int nontermA();
int nontermB();

void match (int terminal){

   if (lookahead == terminal){
      lookahead = getchar();
      } else {
      printf("Syntax error at %c\n", lookahead);
      exit(0);
      }

}

void nontermS(){
   int a,b;
   switch(lookahead){      
      default:
      a = nontermA();
      b = nontermB();
      printf("Match! Number of A's is %d and number of B's is %d", a,b);
      match('\n');
     }

}

int nontermA(){
   int countA = 0;
   switch(lookahead){

      case 'a': match('a'); countA++; nontermA(); break; 
      case 'A': match('A'); countA++; nontermA(); break;
      default: break;   

   }

   return countA;

}

int nontermB(){
   int countB = 0;
   switch(lookahead){
      case 'b': match('b'); countB++; nontermB(); break;
      case 'B': match('B'); countB++; nontermB(); break;
      default: break;
   }
   return countB;

}
```

Basically, if I type in something like "aA", "bB", or "abAB", it should just output the number of a's and b's, but the actual output for my program is just 1 for a and b. I also get a syntax error when I type in "ba", as well as if I input "B".

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where is `lookahead` set before the first call to `match`?, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Both of the `nontermA` and `nontermB` functions exhibit the same logical flaw. The following describes only `nontermA`'s bug, but the same bug also occurs in `nontermB`.

```
 int countA = 0;
```

This declares a new `int` variable that's local to `nontermA`.

```
  case 'a': match('a'); countA++; nontermA(); break;
```

This increments `countA`, and recursively invokes itself.

However each recursive invocation of `nontermA` works exactly like any other function call to `nontermA`: it creates a new local variable named `countA` and initializes it to 0.

The obvious intent here is for the counter to persist across all recursive invocations. But recursion does not work this way.

Each recursive call creates a new `countA` local `int` variable ***for that recursive function call only***, and that's the only thing that gets incremented. That's how C++ works.

The solution is very simple: just return the counter value, have both `nontermA` and `nontermB` return the counter value directly.

```
  case 'a': match('a'); return nontermA()+1;
```

And, otherwise,

```
return 0;
```

when no match occurs.

Comment: It works! It also fixed the bug where it would throw a syntax error at 'B'. Still running into the weird syntax error wen I input 'ba', however. I think that's the fault of either nontermS() or match().

Comment: As defined, the grammar only accepts zero or more `a`s, followed by zero or more `b`s. Your syntax error is consistent with the grammar.